# Python web api using flask

Tags: python, api, rest, service

I am new to python RESTful API, but I got this simple hello world example working for me.

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my attempt to implement an entry point for a web service.

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

tasks = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': u'Buy groceries',
        'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol', 
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': u'Learn Python',
        'description': u'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web', 
        'done': False
    }
]
```

How can I route it so that I can get the task done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to route the user from `localhost` so that you can obtain the desired behaviour.

```
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This way, you have a `get_tasks` function on the `/todo/api/v1.0/tasks`

Comment: I am confused. Using `localhost/todo/...`?

Comment: Instead of using the default `index` route, you use this route to actually call the `get_tasks()` and return a simple json.

Answer (score 0):

The url to hit on the client side would be http://localhost:3000/  (the is usually 3000 for apis but depends on how you launched the server). There are many options for restful apis and flask-restful offers a great flexibility.

Based on this I recommend a framework that I've been working on called Peach(https://github.com/sebastiandev/peach) which is built on top of flask-restful and really speeds things up, allowing you to have a api running in a few minutes. I commend it no only because i built it, but because if was born out of the necessity of a lightweight option to django and other frameworks, flexible enough to adapt it to my needs that would let me built prototypes and simple apps in a breeze.

There are examples and even a virtual machine to test them. Happy coding :)